# Google API Drive V3 retrieving drive storage space used

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

I'm using a google service account to retrieve the usage of data from different users.
I'm using google's python client to authenticate and retrieve the data.

**Code**

```
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=auth)
    result = service.about().get(email).execute();
    result = result.get("storageQuota", {})
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
    method() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I want to be able to get it from a specific user's drive information using the email as an identifier.

Answer (score 3):

### How to get Drive info from yourself

Try this snippet example:

```py
result = service.about().get(fields="*").execute()
result = result.get("storageQuota", {})
print(result)
```

The `print` output is:

```
{'usage': '11638750', 'usageInDrive': '11638750', 'usageInDriveTrash': '7531862'}
```

---

### How to get Drive info from user in your domain

If you are an admin and want to get users info, do the next steps:

1. Create project in [Admin Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/)
2. Create [service account](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts)
3. Go to Admin Console > Security > Advanced settings > [Manage API client access](https://admin.google.com/AdminHome?chromeless=1#OGX:ManageOauthClients)
4. In Client Name put the full email of your created Service Account
5. In One or More API Scopes put `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` and click Authorize
6. Come back to [Service accounts](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts), select your account, **Enable G Suite Domain-wide Delegation**
7. Create **Service Account KEY** (download it as .json)
8. **Activate Drive API** for your project. Go to APIs & Services > [Dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/), click on ENABLE APIS AND SERVICES, search for Drive and Enable it.
9. Create `index.py` file with the next code and launch it:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account

def main():

    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'serviceaccountsproject-81ec0d3c1c1c.json'

    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
    credentials = credentials.with_subject('user@inYourDomain.com')

    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

    result = service.about().get(fields="*").execute()
    result = result.get("storageQuota", {})
    print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And here is an output:

`{'usage': '0', 'usageInDrive': '0', 'usageInDriveTrash': '0'}`

---

### Reference:

- [Google Drive API V3 - About - get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about/get)
- [Understanding service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts)

Comment: I need to be able to get a User's drive space via email or id , I believe your solution will only show the authenticated user's drive space

Comment: Yes because you cant get any information about a users space without the users permission.  They will need to be authenticated first.

Comment: @Meerfallthedewott please take a look on my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

The is an undocumented required paramater with that request. Its called fields.  I have a bug report out.

```
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=auth)
driveRequest = service.about().get(email);
driveRequest.fields = "*";
result = driveRequest.execute();
result = result.get("storageQuota", {})
```

Kindly note i am not a python developer this is a guess on how to do it.

Comment: Would you mind linking the bug report you've mentioned here? This way everyone can keep track of it. Thanks!