# Write to Google Drive using Service Account Credential on behalf of different owner in Python

Tags: python, google-drive-api

When I create a file

```
drive_api = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
ss_drive = drive_api.files().create(body=file_metadata).execute()
```

I'd like to write it on behalf of different owner. Or change the owner afterwards.

```
​'owners': [{'displayName': '1@',
  'emailAddress': '1@',
  'kind': 'drive#user',
  'me': True,
  'permissionId': '1'}],
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Take a look on my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59648637/google-api-drive-v3-retrieving-drive-storage-space-used/59661487#59661487) attention to *How to get Drive info from user in your domain*, next step is just adapt it to your needs. Does it help you?

Comment: you can use permissions create after the file has been uploaded

Comment: @Jeff Rush I'd like to do Domain-wide Delegation without paid GSuite. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @DaImTo Which command does change the `owners`?

Comment: @F.Vosnim you can test google cloud with provided credits, https://cloud.google.com/gcp, I think there are 12 months *free*

Comment: I know that. Thank you. That is not the case. As I know it is impossible to do delegation w/o GSuite. But I found a way to change the owner once a file is created.

Comment: @F.Vosnim May I ask to post your answer explaining how you achieve this?

Comment: @JeffRush It is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60774850/how-to-change-the-owner-with-google-drive-api-v3-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the owner with Google Drive API v3 in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60774850/how-to-change-the-owner-with-google-drive-api-v3-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of documentation.

1. You can create files as other users with Domain Wide Delegation.

   - This requires a G Suite Domain
   - This is also overkill, since Domain Wide Delegation is a **lot** of permissions
2. You can create the files normally then update the permissions to have another user as the OWNER.

   - This can be done with the Drive API [Permissions.Update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/update)
   - You can read about doing this with Python on this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60774850/how-to-change-the-owner-with-google-drive-api-v3-in-python)