# How to change the owner with Google Drive API v3 in Python?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I'm trying to change the owner with Google Drive API by updating the permissions:

```
permissions = drive_api.files().get(fileId=ssId, fields='permissions').execute()['permissions']

[{'displayName': 'account_name',
  'emailAddress': 'account_email',
  'id': 'id1',
  'role': 'writer',
  'type': 'user'},
 {'displayName': 'api_email',
  'emailAddress': 'api_email',
  'id': 'id2',
  'role': 'owner',
  'type': 'user'}]
```

I take my account permission id:

```
for permission in permissions:
  if permission['emailAddress'] == 'account_email':
    permissionId = permission['id']
    break
```

Take the body:

```
body = drive_api.permissions().get(fileId=ssId, permissionId=permissionId).execute()

{'id': 'id1',
 'kind': 'drive#permission',
 'role': 'writer',
 'type': 'user'}
```

Change the role:

```
body['role'] = 'owner'
```

And do the update:

```
drive_api.permissions().update(fileId=ssId, permissionId=permissionId, body=body, transferOwnership=True).execute()
```

But get an error:

> The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed this thing and it started working:

```
body = {
    'id': permissionId,
    'role': 'owner',
}
```

**Shame on Google for this horrible Drive API documentation**